# R problem Resolving Host Github: curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h)

Tags: r, curl, github, devtools, resolve

I have the following problem downloading package from github:

```
>  devtools::install_github('walkerke/tigris') Error in
> curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) :    Could not resolve host:
> api.github.com
```

I was able to do this successfully last night, but then I had some other issues downloading some shapefiles from census. Meanwhile downloading package from github did work. So here is what I did:

1. I unchecked Use IE library/proxy for HTTP and I tried to create a
   new .renviron file with proxy. that did not solve the problem with
   census.
2. I re-checked IE proxy setting, and I deleted the .renviron file that I created (going back to how it was). Now I started having problem with github (resolving host).
3. I removed CURL and HTTR. I reinstalled them. That did not help
4. I deleted CURL and HTTR folder libraries manually and reinstalled them. that did not help.
5. I had R and R studio completely uninstalled, deleted folders and
   then installed. However I still get that error

> "curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) :    Could not resolve host:
>   api.github.com".

I am just trying to get refresh everything I can, to get to the point I was last night when I could do successfully

> devtools::install_github('walkerke/tigris')

without errors resolving host. What else can I do?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try using `remotes` to install. Actually it says the repo isn't found.

Comment: Update: `remotes::install_github("walkerke/tigris")` works for me.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting the same error when I do remotes::. I want to make it clear, that this also worked for me last night, before I did the first step on the list that I wrote above. I just can not do it any more after I did a minor change to proxy that I completely rolled back.